# How to use a SQLCMD variable from within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcmd

What I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @Information VARCHAR(50) = $(ServerInfo)
```

Error:

> SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near $(ServerInfo).

How can I access a SQLCMD variable from within a stored procedure?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106850/pass-parameters-to-a-procedure-with-sqlcmd

Comment: @MitchWheat getting the SQLCMD from within the stored procedure, not passing it to the stored procedure

Comment: @Tarta It's the same thing, really.  You don't have access to the SQLCMD variables from within DDL code.

Comment: @squillman why then if I do **[$(ServerInfo)]** it is able to see the value of the variable? Thing is this solution also doesn't work because eventually it sees the whole thing as a column due to the brackets and therefore will complain about it